# Woo commerce cambiar link de un solo producto

Tags: wordpress

Por defecto, WooCommerce crea un link tanto en la imagen como en el título del producto al ser creado, el cual te lleva a su propia página. Mi intención es cambiar dicho link para llevar al cliente a otra página en la cual puede añadir diseños a dicho producto.

El código a cambiar es este, en el archivo "cart.php"

```
<td class="product-name">
    <?php // Avada edit ?>
    <span class="product-thumbnail">
    <?php
         $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

         if ( ! $_product->is_visible() )
             echo $thumbnail;
         else
             printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', _product->get_permalink( $cart_item ), $thumbnail );
    ?>
    </span>
    <div class="product-info">
    <?php
        if ( ! $_product->is_visible() )
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        else
            // Avada edit
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a class="product-title" href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ), $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

Si no me equivoco para quitar cualquier link tengo que manipular el `else` de la sección `<div class="product-info">` por esta línea:

```
sprintf( '%s', $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

Aqui entra mi pregunta: Cómo llamo al producto al cual quiero cambiar su link con `$_product->id` ?? No se dónde colocarlo en la función ni cómo cambiarle el link sin *pifiarla*...

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Sería una cuestión de usar el `apply_filters` que está disponible. Algo del género:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'apply_filter_9741', 10, 3 );

function apply_filter_9741( $title, $item, $item_key ) {
    $el_enlace = 'http://example.com/enlance/';
    $nuevo_enlace = sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $el_enlace, $title);
    return $nuevo_enlace;
}
```

Este post en Stack Overflow explica cómo usar `$item` y `$item_key` para extraer informaciones extras del carrito: [Get cart item name, quantity all details woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28576667/1287812)